# Entering an input, clicking it and retrieving particular information with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping with Python. My intent is to retrieve the verb for a word of interest. For e.g. dictionary.com has definitions for different parts of speech for word, I would like to enter a word of interest and then hit the search icon, in the resulting page I would like to extract the information under the header 'verb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the information under verb header Induce `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_all_elements_located`()

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.dictionary.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Accept Cookies')]"))).click()
elementsearch=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[title='Search']")))
elementsearch.send_keys("interest")
elementsearch.submit()
results=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='luna-pos'][contains(.,'verb')]/following::div[1]//div[@class='default-content']//div")))
for item in results:
    print(item.text)

results1=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='luna-pos'][contains(.,'verb')]/following::div[1]//div[@class='expandable-content']//div")))
for item in results1:
    print(item.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

**Output on console:**

```
to engage or excite the attention or curiosity of:
Mystery stories interested him greatly.
to concern (a person, nation, etc.) in something; involve:
The fight for peace interests all nations.
to cause to take a personal concern or share; induce to participate: to interest a person in an enterprise.
to cause to be concerned; affect.
```

Comment: Why should the `waiting' happen?

Comment: Browser is taking time to load properly Not the code.The explicit wait is waiting until selenium find the required webelement.